# How to hide an element based on the last index in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I have an array of objects, let's call it `questions`

```js
{questions.length !== lastIndexOfTheQuestionsArray && (
  <ElementToShowIfItIsNotTheLastIndexOfTheQuestionsArray />
)}
```

So that is basically what I need; to hide the `ElementToShowIfItIsNotTheLastIndexOfTheQuestionsArray` element when it reaches the last index of the `questions` array.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Can you give more detail and examples of code that you've already tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `slice` the array to remove the last element before calling `map`.

```
array.slice(0, -1).map(/* ... */)
```